# pivot_table with an index that is not a column of the table

Tags: pandas

In *Pandas for Data Analysis* I came across an example where we have a table with the following columns:

```
name(string) sex(string) year(int) birth(int)
```

The author wants to aggregate on year, sex and last letter of the names so he does:

```
# extract last letter from name column
get_last_letter = lambda x: x[-1]
last_letters = names.name.map(get_last_letter)

last_letters.name = 'last_letter'
table = names.pivot_table(values='births', index=last_letters,
columns=['sex', 'year'], aggfunc=np.sum)
```

I don't quite understand how this pivot_table gets created when `last_letters` is not a column in the table.
Can someone shed some light on how Pandas was able to map `names` to these `last_letters` correctly when aggregating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Columns in `DataFrame` are `Series`, so is possible use `Series` as parameter in `pivot_table`.

So is possible use preprocessing column `name` with custom function for return only last letter, because it return `Series` what is perfect valid input.

Sample:

```
names = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['John','John','John','Josh','Josh','Josh','Sara','Sara','Sara'],
    'births': [10,20,10,40,70,10,20,30,50],
    'year': [1980,1985,1980,1985,1985,1985,1985,1980,1980],
    'sex': ['m','m','m','m','m','m','f','f','f']
})
print (names)
   births  name sex  year
0      10  John   m  1980
1      20  John   m  1985
2      10  John   m  1980
3      40  Josh   m  1985
4      70  Josh   m  1985
5      10  Josh   m  1985
6      20  Sara   f  1985
7      30  Sara   f  1980
8      50  Sara   f  1980
```

---

```
# extract last letter from name column
get_last_letter = lambda x: x[-1]
last_letters = names.name.map(get_last_letter)
last_letters.name = 'last_letter'

print (last_letters)
0    n
1    n
2    n
3    h
4    h
5    h
6    a
7    a
8    a
Name: last_letter, dtype: object

print (type(last_letters))
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

---

```
table = names.pivot_table(values='births', index=last_letters,
                          columns=['sex', 'year'], aggfunc=np.sum)

print (table)
sex             f           m       
year         1980  1985  1980   1985
last_letter                         
a            80.0  20.0   NaN    NaN
h             NaN   NaN   NaN  120.0
n             NaN   NaN  20.0   20.0
```

Comment: Sure, but how does Pandas know that it should aggregate and associate with the index `a` only those `name`s that end in `a`?

Comment: because `last_letters` is Series, please give me some time, I create sample.

Comment: Thanks for the sample! Just to clarify, if i tried to pass the same information as in `last_letters`, but inside a `list` instead of a `Series` it would crash, correct? So does this mean `Series` stores information saying, "I was created from a column in the table" so the table knows what to do if you use it as `index`?

Comment: Good question. Pandas dont know what is Series, but in pivot_table map new Series with DataFrame by index. So `last_letters = pd.Series(['na','na','na','na','ku','ku','ku','ku','ku'])` is perfect valid input too.